# Rhino AutoMocker and Stubs

Tags: rhino-mocks

I am using Joshua Flanagan article “Auto mocking Explained” as a guide.   In the article there is a section called “The same tests, with automocker would look like this”.  I used this information to build code to run the automocker.
As you can see below answer is a list returned from the BLL.   Answer does have one row in it; however,  all fields are null.   So the test for boo fails.   Any tips and hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Test]
        public void GetStaffListAndRolesByTeam_CallBLLWithDALStub()
        {
            // Build List<> data for stub
            List<StaffRoleByTeamCV> stubData = new List<StaffRoleByTeamCV>();
            StaffRoleByTeamCV stubRow = new StaffRoleByTeamCV();
            stubRow.Role = "boo";
            stubRow.StaffId = 12;
            stubRow.StaffName = "Way Cool";
            stubData.Add(stubRow);

            // create the automocker
            var autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<PeteTestBLL>();

            // get instance of test class (the BLL)
            var peteTestBllHdl = autoMocker.ClassUnderTest;

            // stub out call to DAL inside of BLL
            autoMocker.Get<IPeteTestDAL>().Stub(c => c.GetStaffListAndRolesByTeam("4146")).Return(stubData);

            // make call to BLL this should return stubData
            List<StaffRoleByTeamCV> answer = peteTestBllHdl.GetStaffListAndRolesByTeam("4146");

            // do simple asserts to test stubData present
            // this passes
            Assert.IsTrue(1 == answer.Count,  "Did not find any rows"); 
            // this fails
            Assert.IsTrue(answer[0].Role == "boo", "boo was not found");  
        }
```

I tried using MockMode.AAA but still no joy

Answer (score 1):

An new version of AutoMocker (1.0.3) is available. The new version supports relay mode as in this example..

```
[TestMethod]
    public void ShouldSupportOrderedTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var autoMocker = new RhinoAutoMocker<CustomerUpdater>();

        var mockRepository = autoMocker.Repository;

        using (mockRepository.Ordered())
        {
            autoMocker.Get<ICustomerDataProvider>().Expect(x => x.GetCustomer(Arg<int>.Is.Anything)).Return(new CustomerItem());
            autoMocker.Get<ICustomerDataProvider>().Expect(x => x.UpdateCustomer(Arg<CustomerItem>.Is.Anything));
            autoMocker.Get<ILogWriter>().Expect(x => x.Write(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
            autoMocker.Get<ILogWriter>().Expect(x => x.Write(Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
            autoMocker.Get<IMailSender>().Expect(x => x.SendMail(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything));
        }

        //Act
        autoMocker.ClassUnderTest.UpdateCustomerName(1, "Frank", "frank@somecompany.com");

        //Assert
       ExceptionAssert.Throws<ExpectationViolationException>(mockRepository.VerifyAll,"IMailSender.SendMail(anything, anything); Expected #1, Actual #0.\r\nILogWriter.Write(anything); Expected #1, Actual #0.\r\n");  

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but this article suggests that by default all the mocks created by automocker are not replayed:
http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/joshuaflanagan/archive/2008/09/25/arrange-act-assert-with-structuremap-rhinoautomocker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes that was true for the previous version. But was changed to support ordered tests in version 1.0.3.